# How to adjust the vertical space before and after an xltabular, so it is the same as with tabularx

Tags: tabularx, xltabular

I had to replace some tabularx-tables by xltabular-tables, because some tables got too long to fit on one page.

Unfortunately the xltabular introduced additional vertical space before and after each table and I have no idea how to get rid of it.

The following minimal examples show the problem.

Example (tabularx):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

A tabularx:

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
lorem & ipsum \\
\hline
lorem & ipsum \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

Done.

\end{document}
```

which compiles to:

[image]

And with xltabular - Note the **vertical space** before and after the table. (I don't mind the indentation in this example, but it's still questionable too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}

An xltabular:

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
lorem & ipsum \\
\hline
lorem & ipsum \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}

Done.

\end{document}
```

which compiles to:

[image]

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabularx` is an inline element so has no vertical spacing at all. Any vertical space is provided by the surrounding paragraph's settings. Your first example is showing a paragraph with a default zero `\parskip` and then a table that is `\textwidth` wide, indented by `\parindent` so sticking in to the right margin:

```
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--15
```

The second example uses `longtable` so has `\LTpre` and `\LTpost` spaces before and after which you can set with `\setlength`.